# thymeleaf hw to fill th:field value with model attibute

Tags: database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
<input type="hidden" id="customerid" th:value="${id}" th:field="*{customer.id}">
```

id is the model attribute.I want to store it in as customer.id

Answer (score 0):

If you use th:field, you should not specify th:value and id :

```
<input type="hidden"  th:field="*{customer.id}">
```

Source : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs